# @Transactional not working from hibernate interceptor

Tags: java, hibernate

Why transaction is not being created using `@Transactional` when calling from hibernate interceptor?

What I'm trying to achieve is to save some log into database in `afterTransactionCompletion` method.

Roughly it looks like this:

```
@Override
public void afterTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx) {
  someService.transactionalMethod(logToSave);    
}
```

When `transactionalMethod` looks like this:

```
  @Transactional
  public void transactionalMethod(Log log){
     repository.save(log);
  }
```

My log is not being saved without any error.

My `transactionalMethod` is working fine when it is being called from other place rather then interceptor.

Any ideas why?

P.S. Is it even considered an ok practice to call repository method in `afterTransactionalMethod`?